# In a poset, does or doesn't $\ a\sqsubseteq c\ \&\ b\sqsubseteq c\ \ .\mbox{always}\Longrightarrow.\ \ a\sqcup b\sqsubseteq c\ $?

Tags: order-theory

In classical logic, $\ c\Rightarrow a\ \&\ c\Rightarrow b\ \ .\mbox{always}\Longrightarrow.\ \  c\Rightarrow a\&b\ $, although in linear logic that's typically not true (e.g., the vending machine model, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_logic#The_resource_interpretation).

So, correspondingly for posets, does or doesn't $\ a\sqsubseteq c\ \&\ b\sqsubseteq c\ \ .\mbox{always}\Longrightarrow.\ \ a\sqcup b\sqsubseteq c\ $? (that's the main question)
I'm hoping "doesn't always", and if so can you give me an example where it doesn't?

Note that it "always does" for a set-theoretic poset order, where $a\sqsubseteq c$ means $c\subseteq a$, and where $a\sqcup b$ means $a\cap b$.
So we'd necessarily need some other kind of interpretation of poset order for an example where it "doesn't always".

Comment: Usually "$\sqcup$" is defined as the least upper bound operator (note that this **doesn't** always exist in arbitrary posets), in which case - assuming we have least upper bounds in the first place - we trivially have $a\sqcup b\sqsubseteq c$ whenever $a,b\sqsubseteq c$. So in order to make this nontrivial you'll need to clarify exactly what hypotheses you're making about the posets and the meaning of "$\sqcup$" in this question.

Comment: I think, similar to the above comment, we just need more clarification on what $\sqcup$ means in this case. In your example you let it be intersection, but what are we "allowed" to let it be.

Comment: @NoahSchweber (and Bagggggggs) Yeah, I guess we'd need a poset in which $\sqcup$ is defined. My particular interest happens to be domain theory, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_theory, so I might have more narrowly defined my question to that class of posets. But I wanted to leave it as general as possible, i.e., if "doesn't always" (as per the question) is possible, then define $\sqsubseteq$ and $\sqcup$ any mathematically sensible way you'd like such that "doesn't always" for that poset is true. And if you can characterize the most general class of such posets, then that would be great.